# Why did Candor members make good lawyers?

Tags: divergent

The *Divergent* series mentions in passing that Candor members make good lawyers. If that's true, how did they defend people they knew were guilty?

Comment: Why would they know anyone was guilty?

Comment: @Adamant Defense lawyers defend people that they know are guilty all the time.

Comment: It’s far more common that they defend people whom they *believe*  might be guilty. Most real defense lawyers don’t want to know their clients’ guilt, and don’t ask.

Comment: If they think that they *might* be guilty, though, wouldn't that be the same problem? As Candors, if they believed that their client might have been guilty, wouldn't they have to tell the truth about that? It would also be very strange at a minimum for a Candor not to want to know the truth about something.

Comment: EJS - The statement was that Candor  members make good lawyers, and you asked how they could defend people they knew were guilty.  Lawyers also do work like preparing wills, etc., and try cival cases, and prosecute people they don't know are guilty in criminal cases, etc., etc., etc.   So maybe Candor members are good at 95 percent of Lawyer work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Because in real life, lawyers are not allowed to lie.**

Defending a guilty person is not lying.  The job of an attorney is *not* to tell lies to the court on behalf of their client, notwithstanding how the profession is usually portrayed in fiction.  An attorney's job, instead, is to present the relevant facts and law in the light most favorable to their client, and to ensure that their client's rights are respected throughout the process.  Attorneys who routinely lie in court can easily get into [enormous amounts of trouble](https://www.popehat.com/2016/12/16/the-prenda-saga-goes-criminal-steele-and-hansmeier-indicted-on-federal-charges/) for doing so.

Both presenting the facts and law, and defending the rights of the client, involve logic, which is heavily concerned with the relationships between true statements.  The Candor spend enormous amounts of time debating various topics with one another (described in *Insurgent*), and are well versed in logic.  Contrast this with the other four factions:

- Abnegation - Would not be pleased putting their client's needs ahead of those of society as a whole.
- Amity - Would be put off by the [adversarial structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adversarial_system) of American common law.
- Dauntless - Can you seriously imagine a Dauntless lawyer?
- Erudite - Would prefer to follow the facts wherever they lead.

On the other hand, the Candor are very good at compartmentalizing truth, and dealing with it dispassionately (they tell the truth no matter the emotional pain of doing so).  They are therefore better positioned to engage in logical argumentation and debate.

Comment: Dauntless would be perfect for divorces IMHO.

Comment: I'm currently serving on jury duty, so for the last few weeks I've had a front row seat for how true this answer is.

Comment: Good points. Would a Candor have to reveal facts that were unfavorable to their clients, though?

Comment: @EJS: In the course of discovery, almost certainly.  In the main part of the trial, they would not be answering questions in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

lawyers need to prove the innocence of the client using hard facts and make sure their rights are not violated as might happen due to prejudice if the person appears guilty due to circumstance. they don't lie, they twist the truth and highlight stuff that will help the client which is very easy to do for people who live life on principles of truth.

They are perfect for the job mainly because they are exactly the people experienced to manipulate truth without lying throughout their lives. people usually lie a lot in life and if these group of people can't or won't lie then they have to get through life through the art of telling lies without actually telling lies.

Comment: A Candor deliberately twisting the truth seems implausible to me.

Comment: even twisted, it is still the truth.

Comment: I guess so... still seems strange to me though.